# How to store a list of closures returning a Future and share it between threads in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to write a multi-thread TCP server that can handle multiple connections at the same time with `tokio`.

I want to structure it in an event-driven way, where it's possible to attach one or more closures to a specific event (like new connection, message received, client disconnected etc).

For example:

```
    server.on_message(|msg: String, stream: &mut TcpStream| {
       async move {
            println!("Recieved {:?}", msg);
            stream.write_all(b"Hello\n").await;
       }
    }).await;
```

Every connection will receive its own thread which should have read access to a `Vec` of callbacks.

```
    pub async fn run(&mut self) {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:9090").await.unwrap();

        loop {
            let (mut socket, _) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();

            let cb = self.on_message.clone();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                Self::process(socket, cb).await;
            });
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, my understanding of Rust is still very rudimentary and I run in circles with:

- finding the right type to be stored in Vec
- finding the right type for function argument that takes closure callback

Whenever I feel like I make progress in one place then I realise the other got messed up. This is the best I could do but it still doesn't work.

```
type Callback<T> = dyn Fn(T, &mut TcpStream) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=()> + Send>> + Send + 'static;

unsafe impl<T> Send for TcpStreamCallbackList<T> {}
unsafe impl<T> Sync for TcpStreamCallbackList<T> {}

impl<T> TcpStreamCallbackList<T> {

    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { callbacks: Vec::new() }
    }

    pub fn push<G: Send + 'static>(&mut self, mut fun: impl Fn(T, &mut TcpStream) -> G + Send + 'static) where G: Future<Output=()> {
        self.callbacks.push(Arc::new(Box::new(move |val:T, stream: &mut TcpStream| Box::pin(fun(val, stream)))));
    }

    pub async fn call(&self, val: T, stream: &mut TcpStream) where T: Clone {
        for cb in self.callbacks.iter() {
            let _cb = cb.clone();
            _cb(val.clone(), stream).await; // B O O M

        }
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't compile until I remove `.await` on the Future returned by callback in the `call` function (which defeats the purpose).

```
error[E0277]: `dyn for<'a> Fn(String, &'a mut tokio::net::TcpStream) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = ()> + std::marker::Send>> + std::marker::Send` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:94:26
```

From what I understand the problem is that the retuned Future is not Send.

```
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /Users/lukasz/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.25.0/src/task/spawn.rs:163:21
    |
163 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
```

I have no idea if my type makes sense and is thread-safe. I also don't know why the compiler thinks the return type is not Send. I'm really stuck here and would appreciate any help.

Comment: werid if i cargo check it, its fine

Comment: sorry, I used confusing language. I should say it compiles until I add ".await". I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together one that is slightly simpler but can be spawned [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca546719bf31847ea481ccce755bcda0). The key is that `Callback` needs to be `Sync` in order for `&self` to be `Send`. I tried to use the trick mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75403078/using-dyn-async-traits-with-async-trait-crate-in-spawned-tokio-task/75405800#comment133056761_75405800), but it doesn't appear to work here, nor does making `call` take `&mut self`. I wrote more about `Send` and `Sync` on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75405800/6274355).

```rs
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

type CallbackFuture<O> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = O> + Send>>;
type Callback<T> = dyn (Fn(T) -> CallbackFuture<()>) + Send + Sync;

pub struct CallbackList<T> {
    list: Vec<Box<Callback<T>>>,
}

impl<T> CallbackList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { list: Vec::new() }
    }

    pub fn push<F>(&mut self, f: F)
    where
        F: Fn(T) -> CallbackFuture<()>,
        F: Send + Sync + 'static,
    {
        self.list.push(Box::new(f))
    }

    pub async fn call(&self, t: T)
    where
        T: Clone,
    {
        for f in &self.list {
            f(t.clone()).await;
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut calls = CallbackList::new();
    calls.push(|i| {
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("{i}");
        })
    });

    calls.push(|i| {
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("{}", i + 1);
        })
    });

    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        calls.call(34).await;
    });

    handle.await.unwrap();
}
```

I have removed as many trait bounds, `'static`s, and wrappers as possible, but you may need to add some back depending on what you do with it. Right now it takes `T`, but it should be possible to separate that into `T` and `&mut TcpStream`. If you update your question with a `main` function that uses all the elements, I can change mine to match. If all else fails, you can use `(_, Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>)` as `T`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I find your answer very helpful. My main problem as you said was missing the `Sync`. I also appreciate your example as you structure types in a much cleaner way, for example I didn't know I can use `F` more than once after `where`.